# Calling overridden method from non-overridden method uses base class implementation

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, methods

I have a method call in a base class that looks like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface BaseController : NSObject

-(void)login;

@end
```

---

```
#import "BaseController.h"

@implementation BaseController

-(void)performTask
{
 return @"Base method loaded";
}


-(void)login
{
 [self performTask];
}


-(id)init
{
 if ((self = [super init]))
 {

 }

 return self;
}

-(void)dealloc
{
 [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

---

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "BaseController.h"

@interface DerivedController : BaseController

-(void)performTask;

@end
```

---

```
#import "DerivedController.h"

@implementation DerivedController

-(void)performTask
{
 NSLog(@"Inherited method loaded.");
}

-(id)init
{
 if ((self = [super init])) { }

 return self;
}

-(void)dealloc
{
 [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

I would like to override the method `performTask` in a derived class and have the unchanged `login` method call the overridden method.  This should be easy.  What am I missing?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? When you override `performTask` in your subclass, instances of your subclass will use the overridden `performTask` method in `callingMethod`.

Comment: No repro; this works as expected for me. Is this a copy-paste of the code that's causing you trouble?

Comment: Please post the code where you create an instance of the subclass and call the method.

Comment: Found my mistake, I was initializing my derived class with the alloc method of the base class.  What a stupid mistake.  Thanks @Terry Wilcox for the advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just override `performTask` and the subclass instance will automatically use its own implementation when it receives the `performTask` message.

Comment: I overrode performTask, but the parent class method was still called.  I thought this might have to do with the fact that I needed to override callingMethod too.  Maybe this is because the message is sent to "self" by the parent.

Comment: Are you sure you overrode the method properly, i.e. with exactly the same signature? Are you sure you created the subclass and not the Base class in your test? How does the init method of the derived class look?

Comment: The overriding method has the same return type and number of arguments.  The super keyword is not used.  The init method sets self = [super init] .  Anything look fishy?

Comment: @Patrick Hogan: `self` is the object that's responding to the message, whatever it might be. If it's not working for you, try posting a more complete example of code that exhibits the problem, because this is how it's done in Objective-C and it works in all the other programs out there, so the problem must be some detail of your code that you haven't mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for keeping up with this.  I posted more code above.  As a side  note, I have tried overriding the login method, too.  And still the base class method is called.  Very strange.

Comment: @Patrick Hogan: I don't think the problem is with how you define your methods. I think it's how you're calling them. Can you post the code that calls `login` and specifically how the DerivedController instance is being created?

Comment: Thanks Chuck, stupid typo in instantiation of derived object.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Chuck, just override the method, but pay attention to not call [super performTask] in your new implementation.

Comment: Only if the super performTask processing is not wanted. If an override is supposed to **extend** the base method, it makes sense to invoke the super method first.

Comment: This is the case that Patrick want

Comment: I can't derive that from his question.